# How to point to the root of a dynamically generated tree in C?

Tags: c

I'm writing a small compiler in C for a homework and I need to free the memory allocated for the AST nodes in case of a syntax error or if the program runs out of memory.

The AST is generated dynamically, the nodes are defined as structs that hold the kind of node (program, var, cst, expression, statement, assignment, etc.), their values and their children.

I wrote a recursive method that parses the tree and then frees the nodes one by one. But in order for that to work, I need the first node, as in, the root of the tree. Is there any way I can have a global variable that stores the address to that first dynamically generated node? I already tried declaring a *node pointer 'start', and when the first node 'x' is created, adding 'start = x' but that leads to problems down the road (every NULL children in the tree becomes a BAD_ACCESS error)

So in short, I need to be able to reference the first node created later in the program. Help?

Comment: re. `NULL` children causing errors, you need to remove references to deallocated nodes. If you have only links from parent to child node, this means your recursive deallocation should inform the parent to remove the link when you deallocate a node.

Comment: The method to free the memory isn't the problem. When I debug, the memory is already corrupted on the very first iteration of the algorithm

Comment: Regarding which node is the "root", that would be the AST node that is child to no one, but without knowing what your AST looks like or how it's stored, its pure guesswork how you would determine that; *no one* knows your AST better than *you* do, since you wrote it.

Comment: My question is basically; how can I store in a global variable the address of a value that is generated dynamically, so that I can point to it later in the program?

Comment: The answer to that question is "yes", and based on what you write above you even did it already. Your actual problem seems to be the memory corruption, e.g., you might be allocating too little space for your nodes or leaving pointers to deallocated nodes.

Comment: Anyway, there isn't really sufficient information to help you here. Perhaps try to create a minimal example that demonstrates the problem, e.g., only create one node without any actual parsing, such as by implementing the two functions in `root = createAST(); parseAST(root);`